# Set Microsoft Edge Start Page Registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

What are the registry key(s) to set the Start Page url (not the Home Page) for Microsoft Edge on Win10?

[image]

Comment: Please better define what you mean by "Start Page" if you don't mean "Home Page".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Protected - It is a violation of Windows Policy to modify. See aka.ms/browserpolicy\ProtectedHomepages`...though it's harder to edit than you think. According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137355/3427178) on a similar question on Stack Overflow, it's an encrypted value that can be backed up and restored only to the same PC.

Another user in that thread linked their [research](https://www.ntkernel.com/microsoft-edge-protectedhomepages/) in reverse-engineering the encryption. It only reads the stored homepage value instead of writing it, but the process should be reversible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to this page :

[image]

If you want to change this page to something customized you have two options:

Change the "Start Page" AKA "Startup Page" by Using :

**URL (Link to another page):**

You can use a website link (URL) or a local page (A page that is saved on your computer).

To add a local page link:

1. Change "Open Microsoft Edge With" option to "A specific page or
   pages".

   2. Now, use the local page that you have by adding its link.  *(Example: file://D:/mydemofiles/EdgeFirstPageDemo.html)*
   3. Save your settings and restart Edge browser.

For the website page, you do the same process but use the website link instead of your local link.

**Registery Key:** 
You'll find a good guide at this link : [How to Change Microsoft Edge Startup Page in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5090-change-startup-page-microsoft-edge.html)